# What special meaning do square braces have in a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, split, square-bracket, character-class

Can anyone explain me this code  split("[ ]+", $s);
thanks

```
$s = "Split this sentence by spaces";
$words = split("[ ]+", $s);
print_r($words);

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => Split
    [1] => this
    [2] => sentence
    [3] => by
    [4] => spaces
)
```

Comment: Wait, is that a singleton character class? WhereTF do these come from? They don't make the slightest sense, yet I've seen them two or three times on SO alone o.O

Comment: Hey, it splits a string using a regex(note that split is deprecated, use preg_split or explode). Split function uses "simple" regex (but not Perl compatible Regex). The regex : [ ]+ matches One or Several spaces.

Comment: @delnan It makes it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split string into array by regular expression. [This function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

I reccommend 'explode' function instead 'split':

```php
$s = "Split this sentence by spaces";
$words = explode(" ", $s);

print_r($words);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
 [0]=>
 string(5) "Split"
 [1]=>
 string(4) "this"
 [2]=>
 string(8) "sentence"
 [3]=>
 string(2) "by"
 [4]=>
 string(6) "spaces"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The first argument to [split](http://www.php.net/split) is a regex pattern, which in this instance is effectively saying "match the space character as many times as possible".

**N.B.: split is deprecated as of PHP 5.3, so I wouldn't recommend using this.**

You could achieve precisely the same effect via:

```
$words = explode(" ", $s);
```

See the [explode manual page](http://www.php.net/explode) for more info.

Comment: @Jim No problem. Incidentally, once you feel your question has been answered, if you select your favourite answer (via the grey tick below the vote count on the left of each answer) you'll obtain reputation points for yourself and the person who posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It splits the given string into an array by the regular expression "[ ]+" which matches one or more spaces. It could technically just be " +" but since its a space, it is more readable with the brackets.

Note that the split function has been depreciated since version 5.3, and you should use preg_split instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php).

`split`'s first argument is a regular expression which describes what the delimiter looks like. In your case, `"[ ]+"` (which can also be written simply as `" +"`) means "one or more spaces".

Answer (score 0):

```
"[ ]+"
```

Is a regex expression.  It will split the string according to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The [`split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) function can take regular expression as its argument too. In your case, you specify `[ ]+` which means:

```
[ ]   // a character class is used with a space
 +    // find one or more instances of space
```

Hence, when you do:

```
$words = split("[ ]+", $s);
```

An array is created and stored in `$words` variable with all letters delimited by space.

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

---

***Note*** that `split` function is deprecated. You can do the same things with `explode` like this:

```
$s = "Split this sentence by spaces";
$words = explode(' ', $s);
print_r($words);
```